# Is there any JavaScript native way of creating a raw TCP Socket for the client side?

Tags: javascript, sockets, tcp

I need to create a raw TCP Socket connection from the client side (browser) in JavaScript. Is there any native (language supported) way of crating or working with TCP Sockets. I need the TCP Connection, not a WebSocket neither any HTTP backed solution.

Comment: I think that's what node.js is about, though the socket is not raw. http://nodejs.org/

Comment: No. Browsers only support ws and http/s. You will have to use a plugin written in flash or silverlight or alike to have more native access to be able to make TCP connection

Comment: Not from within a browser. Client-side JavaScript can only use web-related standards like HTTP/Ajax and WebSockets. If you need raw TCP, you will need a server-side layer to create the TCP socket.

Comment: But do check this library out: https://github.com/yankov/webtcp

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: i think chrome extensions might have this capability, but not vanilla JS.

Comment: Thanks for the English class.