# Frontend raw TCP/UDP sockets in a browser, any way at all in 2021?

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, raw-sockets, python-sockets

I've seen many questions about using raw TCP/UDP sockets in web browsers using JavaScript/Html5 however they are all old like [this one posted 5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27989053/is-there-any-javascript-native-way-of-creating-a-raw-tcp-socket-for-the-client-s). It is now 2021 and I'm wondering if there is any possibility at all to avoid using WebSockets and instead use raw TCP/UDP sockets so my local Web page can talk with my local Python socket server.

I don't mind if it's not accessible via internet, or if I need an extension as it's only for a home project where a web page on my Raspberry Pi zero will communicate with my main computer to request data via its Python socket server.

I know that Chrome apps had a socket API before the apps were dropped and I saw this [article about Chromium devs wanting to add sockets](https://www.theregister.com/2020/08/22/chromium_devices_raw_sockets/), but failed to find any real info about it.

Does anyone know of any way to use raw TCP/UDP sockets in a browser?

Comment: For different security reasons, not to mention the ease with which browsers run untrusted scripts from websites, I doubt if we will **ever** see raw TCP / UDP on a browser. If we do, then initiating a DDoS (Distributed Denial of Service) attack might become too easy for the internet to survive this "feature".

Comment: It makes sense, however I was hoping that like for Same-Origin AJAX requests, you could somehow allow sockets at your own risk if you chose to. I'll keep waiting in case it gets added at some point then

Comment: Good luck, Just remember: a feature that can be enabled for some things or under some circumstances can be hacked / abused. A feature that doesn't exist can't ever be hacked... I think you might have a long wait ahead of you.